# How to save my variable input to the original batch file after I have typed it into the command prompt?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to save my input for %x% to the Batch file once I type it in the command prompt. Please see below.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Access to OST Documents for this project
ECHO Please enter the name of the OST Documents folder you would like to acces. (Spelling Sensitive)
set /p x= "P:\OST Documents\"
if not exist "P:\OST Documents\%x%" goto :try_again 
if exist "P:\OST Documents\%x%" Goto :Continue

:Try_again
Echo Location not found, please try again.
set /p x= "P:\OST Documents\"

:Continue
TITLE Access to OST Documents for this project

:choice
set /P c=Are you sure you want to continue[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :OST_Documents_File
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :end
goto :choice

:OST_Documents_File
Start "" "P:\OST Documents\%x%"
End

:end
Fail
End
```

Comment: You should be using this style/syntax, `Set /P "x=P:\OST Documents\"`. However, I would suggest it would be better to present the end user with a list of the existing directories to choose from, instead of letting them guess and then checking their input.

Comment: Why is that preferred?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
call :getvar
if not "%x%" == "" goto :continue
REM var not set; ask user:
REM insert your input code and verification here
REM write it to the end of this batch:
echo set "x=%x%">>"~f0"
:continue
REM rest of your code
REM the following line should be the very last line in this batch (but WITH a CRLF):
:getvar
```

The `call :getvar` tries to set the variable (comes back empty for the first run)
The `if` line checks, if empty (then the user gets asked)
`echo set "x=%x%">>"~f0"` is the key here. It adds the `set command` to the batch file (`%~f0` is the batch file's full name), so
`call :getvar` comes back with the previously set variable `%x%`

Comment: Assume, `%x%` is `5`- Then `echo set "x=%x%"` echoes `set "x=5". `>>` redirects that to `%~f0`, which is the fully qualified filename (drive, path, name, and extension) of the currently running batchfile (in other words: "append `set "x=5"` to myself")

Comment: my other comment deleted somehow, for other's reference I asked

@stephan to explain `echo set "x=%x%">>"~f0"`