# Rewrite running batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wanted to see if there was a way to rewrite the batch script executing code by itself. I'm aware of the possibility of creating another batch file to do the task.

Example Code of what I want to achieve,

```
@echo off
title Self Re-Writing Program

set /p answer="> "
if %answer%=="1" (goto mode1)

:mode1
REM some code here to re-write itself with custom content


REM Exit Program
exit
```

Comment: you can *add* code at the end of your running script, you can even *change* code *after the currently executing code*. But never change code before the currently executed line. The parser "remembers" at which position of the code it should continue (not per line count, but per byte count!) So adding or removing chars before the currently executing line will force the parser to execute a crippled line. Very probably this will end in a syntax error. And you don't know, what will be executed, when not...

Comment: @Stephan I understand what you are saying, I realized I had asked such a question without research and on a whim. Thank you for clarifying it for me, it was my fault that I did not spend enough time looking into it. I appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Comment: Write a batchfile with custom content and `call` it from your main batch.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use subroutines or macro's that can perform actions using the value of the argument recieved via user input?

Comment: @T3RR0R not really, I implemented multiple files and just called upon them, as they were the most logical idea. I just wanted to stick to one file, for the sake of simplicity LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code at the end of your running script, you can even change code after the currently executing code. But never change code before the currently executed line. The parser "remembers" at which position of the code it should continue (not per line count, but per byte count!) So adding or removing chars before the currently executing line will force the parser to execute a crippled line. Very probably this will end in a syntax error.

Answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan

Comment: I used a (very simple) version of "self modifying code" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55694870/2152082)

Comment: @Stephan broooo, I was looking into something similar. But could not find it on Google so I stuck to using another file. This works perfectly for what I need, thanks homie <3