# Reading & Writing a single line of a string variable to a text file in batch script..?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm making a small program/routine in batch script;

whereby I ask a user to input an ip address.

I want to take that input, & save it,

& load it the next time the program runs so that it could be processed without user inputting it again.
here's a summary/snippet of my code

```
:load
< lastip.txt (
I want to load %ip%
)

:choice
rem if lastip.txt exists
rem redirects user to somewhere
rem else goes to start depending upon user input

:start rem User inputs Ip here
cls
echo.
echo Input ip, its ipv4 I guess.
set /p %ip%="ip: "
goto save

:save
(
I want To save %ip%
) > lastip.txt
pause
goto somewhere
```

maybe this has been asked before but I wasn't able to implement any existing solutions in this use case; forgive me..
batch-scripting used to be so easy, maybe I'm not getting along with the syntax, hoping some one could help me on this holy platform?

edit:
initially I asked;

Saving & Loading a string variable in batch script..?

later I realized that saving and loading is not the same as reading and writing.. at least in my use case so I changed the question, Lol.

Comment: To load  it from the first line of your text file, use either `0< "lastip.txt" (Set /P "ip=")` or `(Set /P "ip=") 0< "lastip.txt"`.

Comment: Considering that you have the syntax correct except for the actual commands that would write to a file and read from a file, I have to suspect that you were incredibly close; you're right in thinking that this is going to be very simple. What commands did you try that failed?

Comment: maybe you like [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694519/how-to-save-my-variable-input-to-the-original-batch-file-after-i-have-typed-it-i)

Comment: @SomethingDark I tried

echo %ip%

and I also tried 

set /p ip=

where I want to save %ip% but its not working apparently.. maybe I'm loading iit incorrectly, idk really,

Comment: @Compo thanks; the loading is working now, only left with saving, maybe my saving is not over writing a text file..I guess..

Comment: @Stephan in my use case I can't use call for some reason.. thought your alternative works fine, I tested it too, thanks..

Comment: To save it as the first, and only line of your text file, use either `1> "lastip.txt" (Echo=%ip%)` or `(Echo=%ip%) 1> "lastip.txt"`.

Comment: uh? `Call` is an internal command. I can't think of any reason for it to not work (except using it wrong, for example, no colon or a missing label)

Comment: @Stephan its working fine, I'm just not allowed to use call

Comment: BTW, I would strongly advise that you perform some validation of any user input, instead of assuming that the end user will only input what you expect them to. _The most important thing to remember when writing code is that there is an imbecile using it, who cares nothing about your code or intent_. You need to ensure at the very least that they're entering four sequences of one or more integers separated by only periods.

Comment: @Compo thank you so much, validation is implemented, thanks for reminding this is just a snippet of one of many subroutines of our class project.

could you write both the read and write syntax as an answer so I could upvote and select it as an answer; if something really better doesn't come up.. or would you like me to do it for you?

also do you know of any sources where I could brush up my syntax for batch script.

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer yourself @tinku007, _a few points means nothing to me_.

Comment: Also take account that an end user can enter nothing at all, or anything they want, at a `Set /P` prompt, so as well as validating their input, you also need to have code which doesn't crash everything, if they enter characters like these `"^&()|<>`.

Comment: @compo I'm using integer validation in main program whereby each x of xxx.xx.xx.x should be an integer and neq 0 or less than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using **one line of text file**,

To ***save*** it as the first, and only line of your text file, use either

```
1> "lastip.txt" (Echo=%ip%)
```

OR

```
(Echo=%ip%) 1> "lastip.txt"
```

To ***load*** it from the first line of your text file,
use either

```
0< "lastip.txt" (Set /P "ip=")
```

OR

```
(Set /P "ip=") 0< "lastip.txt"
```

From textbook point of view; instead of saving & loading this is rather writing & reading from a text file using batch script if I'm not wrong but it should get the job done.

I would however be eager to know more on this if anyone else could redirect. that would be great.

thanks to @compo for the courtesy of this answer.